# Rendering jbuilder json from rspec api spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, testing, rspec, jbuilder

I'm writing specs for a Rails api in a similar fashion to that described in Chapter 13 of [Rails 3 in Action](http://www.manning.com/katz/).

In the book, they compare json responses using the result of `#to_json`.

```
expect(response.body).to eql(project.to_json)
```

I, however, am using jbuilder, so this will not work. I need a way to render the jbuilder template and get the response in the example but have been unsuccessful in doing so so far.

My test are located in the spec/api directory and marked as `type: :api` as directed in the book. I include the ApiHelper module for :api specs in the rspec config, which includes Rack::Test::Method, (but this actually doesn't seem to make much of a difference anyway).

It seems the `#render` method used in other rspec tests could work, but it's not available in my api spec and I don't know how to make it so.

A full example spec looks like this.

```
# spec/api/photos_spec.rb

require "spec_helper"

describe "Photos Api", type: :api do
  let(:user)  { create(:user) }
  let(:token) { user.authentication_token }
  let(:photo) { create(:photo) }

  let(:url) { "/api/photos" }
  it "should get a photo" do
    get "#{url}/#{photo.id}.json", token: token
    expect(response).to be_ok
    expect(response.body).to eql("???") # How can I get the jbuilder output for comparison?
  end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your Jbuilder output *is* `response.body`. What you need to compare it against is what you have mocked out.

```
expect(response.body).to include(photo.url)
```

Usually, checking output of views is best tested within request specs via Capybara or what have you even though Rspec allows you to specify `render_views` within your controller specs.